# Match words and sentences between HTML tags while ignoring whitespaces at the beginning and the end

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to write a simple regex to select texts inside HTML tags inside of my editor (VSCode).

The following regex almost achieved that, except that it selects words only and not sentences, for containing whitespaces.

```
>\s*?([^\s^@^<]+?)\s*<
```

I would like to extend that regex to match sentences as well.

Comment: The regex flavor is not PCRE in VSCode, the option there is called PCRE2, but it does not use the actual PCRE2 nor PCRE regex engine.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
>\s*?([^\s^@^<]+?)\s*<
```

try

```
>\s*([^@<>]*?)\s*<
```

(remove `\s` from forbidden characters in range, remove non-greedy quantifier `?`)

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/1g1Z5k/2).

I am not sure why you remove the `@` from the allowed characters. You may get unexpected results, depending on the actual content.

Comment: well, thank you very much.. that'll do for me for now. But that will match white spaces between two tags, not only text. https://regex101.com/r/1g1Z5k/3

Comment: It will match only the white-spaces between words. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Moreover, you should use `*?` instead of `+?`. It will not catch any space which is not a word separator.

Comment: See: Match2-Group1. it matched a white space as a group, that is not desired behaviour.

Comment: It still matches white spaces unfortunately. See: Match2-Group2 in https://regex101.com/r/1g1Z5k/6  .. Which would be a mess in a replace all situation

Comment: You know that it catches spaces by testing in VS? Regarding replacements, if the length of the found string is zero, then do no replacement. Right now I cannot think of something better :(  Also, I do not see a Match2-Group2, only Group 1 for all matches - at the link you provided